# Dog Age to Human Year Console Application

Tags: vb.net

Good Day fellow Stackoverflow guyz, I have a problem with my code, The value of the last line is always zero. I don't know why if my Public Function is right or wrong but I feel it's just in there.

```
Imports System

Public Class Dog

Private Dogname As String
Private DogAge As Integer
Private ToHumanAge As Integer
Private DogBreed As String

Public Sub AcceptDetails()
    Console.Write("Enter Dog's Name: ")
    Dogname = Console.ReadLine
    Console.Write("Enter Age in calendar years: ")
    DogAge = Console.ReadLine
    Console.Write("Enter Dog's Breed: ")
    DogBreed = Console.ReadLine
End Sub
Public Function GetDogAge()

    If DogAge <= 2 Then
        GetDogAge = DogAge * 11
    Else
        GetDogAge = (((DogAge - 2) * 5) + 22)
    End If
    End
End Function
Public Sub Display()
    Console.WriteLine("Dog Name: " & Dogname)
    Console.WriteLine("Dog Breed: " & DogBreed)
    Console.WriteLine("Dog Age to Human:" & GetDogAge())
    Console.Read()
End Sub
End Class
Module Module1
Sub Main()
    Dim D As New Dog()
    D.AcceptDetails()
    D.Display()
    Console.Read()
End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning the value that you got from the function,
i adjusted it a bit, here's my version:

```
Module Dog
Private Dogname As String
Private DogAge As Integer
Private DogBreed As String

Sub Main(args As String())
    AcceptDetails()
    Display()
    Console.Read()
End Sub

Public Sub AcceptDetails()
    Console.Write("Enter Dog's Name: ")
    Dogname = Console.ReadLine
    Console.Write("Enter Age in calendar years: ")
    DogAge = Console.ReadLine
    Console.Write("Enter Dog's Breed: ")
    DogBreed = Console.ReadLine
End Sub

Public Function GetDogAge()

    If DogAge <= 2 Then
        GetDogAge = DogAge * 11
    Else
        GetDogAge = (((DogAge - 2) * 5) + 22)
    End If
    Return GetDogAge
End Function

Public Sub Display()
    Console.WriteLine("Dog Name: " & Dogname)
    Console.WriteLine("Dog Breed: " & DogBreed)
    Console.WriteLine("Dog Age to Human:" & GetDogAge())
    Console.Read()
End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: thank you very much I've get it when i posted it i miss this Dim ToHuman As Integer
        GetDogAge = ToHuman